# Packages.config file and references are not adding to projects in NuGets, why?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

After installing the External package from other sources in the solution, it is not creating the ‘packages.config’ file in the projects and  the references are not being added.

FYI
If i used other NuGet packages from nuget.org they are creating this file and adding references.

Comment: Which NuGet package specifically? There is no NuGet package that has the package id of just 'External'.

Comment: The packages given by my company, which are hosted in company's local address.

Comment: Without seeing what is in the NuGet package it will be difficult to work out what the problem is. I would look at an existing NuGet package that works from nuget.org and compare it with the External package you are using. I would guess that it is being treated as a solution level NuGet package and has no assemblies in it.

Comment: For me also existing NuGet packages(from nuget.org) are working fine, How can i look into a NuGet package ?How can i Identify problem with my nuget packages?

Comment: A NuGet package (.nupkg) is just a .zip file. So a simple way is to rename it to be .zip and then extract it the files. I would look at the lib directories, which is where assemblies are normally stored. Otherwise just compare the files with a NuGet package from nuget.org that works.